# Serialization problem in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When we try to deserialize a Model from our database we always receive a YAML object. For that we added the following code in the environment.rb:

```
YAML.add_domain_type("ActiveRecord,2007", "") do |type, val|
  klass = type.split(":").last.constantize
  YAML.object_maker(klass, val)
end

class ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_yaml_type
    "!ActiveRecord,2007/#{self.class}"
  end
end

class ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_yaml_properties
    ['@attributes']
  end
end
```

This works! But only once, when I refresh the screen I always `undefined method ... for YAML`. It seems like my code isn't executed anymore...

Can anyone help?

Thnx!

Answer (score 0):

1. it's not a good idea to serialize a full active record object. The object might change in the meantime and, when you load it, you might find yourself working with a stale object.
2. be sure the class definition of the object you are deserializing is loaded before the object is deserialized. Normally, you won't need to `require` the class because it's automatically loaded by Ruby when you try to use it. This doesn't happen when you deserialize an object.